# Some dialogs do not work anymore in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Some dialogs are broken on my system.
This includes:
- some file selection dialogs (open and save). Not all of them though. File selection dialogs in some Qt apps (including Qt demo) don't work anymore (when using native dialogs) and file selection dialogs in Visual Studio 2010 do not work anymore. (They do work in visual studio 2008).
- most of the dialogs in Visual Studio 2010, such as add reference, or icon dialog, but not the preferences dialog.

I have tried to find the problem in other applications, with no luck. File dialogs work fine in for example MS Paint and Office 2007. Some applications use "old" file selection dialogs (with Windows 98 style buttons), and those work too. Some software that uses Qt does have working file selection dialogs.

Edit: when the dialog should show up, the main window loses focus (just like it would when a dialog does show up), but then regains focus after about 0.1 second.

Perhaps this is a problem with a specific window flag?

I would appreciate anything that can help me solve this problem, as Visual Studio is virtually unusable now.

OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: Sounds like your .NET install(s) is (are) corrupt.

Comment: I completely removed all my .NET installations and re-installed them. Unfortunately this did not fix the problem.

Comment: Have these ever worked for you on this machine? Have you changed anything since then?

Comment: Yes, they did work. I suppose I changed something but unfortunately I can't remember what.

Comment: If they did work previously, and it's a recent breakage, have you tried a system restore?

Comment: No, I didn't because system restore also restores things that souldn't be restored. Re-installing Windows will probably solve the problem too, but if there is a better solution I would prefer that. I'll try system restore, as I don't have an other option right now.

Comment: System Restore ONLY restores registry files and configuration, etc.  It doesn't touch data.  You should try it.

Comment: Yes, so anything you installed after the restore point that changed a configuration will break, but leave it's files on the HDD, sometimes making it difficult to properly un-install it. But I will try a system restore.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no recovery points from before the problem. Other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the problem after a better web search. Thanks very much to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditorprerelease/thread/75ccebe3-ed80-4ade-acc1-22bda119391e) page. The solution was to turn the Tablet PC input service on again.
To do so, go to Computer Management -> Services and Applications and turn on Tablet PC Input Service.

Comment: too bad that the link doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: I added more details to the answer, I hope this helps you.

Comment: Perfect!  This fixed my problem after I started the service and then restarted Visual Studio.  I'd been dealing with this problem for more than a year.... :)